# Doesn't change the format of columns to date

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

Can any one point out what's wrong with the part where it changes the format of the columns to Date? It worked before but now for some reason it doesn't change the format anymore. Thanks in advance.

```
   With wsMain
       .Columns("A:AO").AutoFit
       .Cells.ClearFormats
       .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
       .Cells.Font.Name = "Georgia"
       .Cells.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 225)
       .Cells.Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).Interior.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
       .Columns(9).NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
       .Columns(11).NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
       .Columns(17).NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
       .Columns(18).NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
       .Columns(20).NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
       .Columns(22).NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
       .Columns(23).NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
       .Columns(29).NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
```

Comment: Code looks fine to me.  I'd verify you have actual dates in those columns instead of text that looks like a date

Comment: Works fine here to. could also check for merged cells they cause havoc... also for purpose of testing you could use .clearformats (which will remove all format(s/ing)) on one of the columns and see if that works. Or just try typing numbers in the columns and they should changed to dates (for testing purposes)

Comment: It works for me in both .xls and .xlsx formats.

Comment: Thanks guys for prompt responses

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the data is still marked as "Text" despite the column formatting.  I bet if you do a Find/Replace on that column by replacing "/" with "/" (yes - replace a slash with the same slash character), Excel will recognise the newly replaced values as dates and format them appropriately.  It's a quirk in Excel.  If possible, you should be running the NumberFormat code before you introduce data in those columns.